# Parse XML with XPath In PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I need to echo only ID and title , I have used Xpath with xml to get the details ... I need to echo the ID  and title for each  in a seperate line ...

```
<?php
$xml = <<< XML
<data>
    <metadata>
        <total_elements>183</total_elements>
        <elements_per_page>100</elements_per_page>
        <total_pages>2</total_pages>
    </metadata>
    <spl>
        <id>ID1</id>
        <version>2</version>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <published_date>Oct 06, 2017</published_date>
    </spl>
    <spl>
        <id>ID2</id>
        <version>2</version>
        <title>Title 2</title>
        <published_date>Oct 05, 2017</published_date>
    </spl>
    <spl>
        <id>ID3</id>
        <version>2</version>
        <title>Title 3</title>
        <published_date>Oct 04, 2017</published_date>
    </spl>
</data>
XML;

$errorSetting = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->loadXML($xml);
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($errorSetting);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($feed);

foreach ($xpath->query('//spl') as $spl) {
    foreach ($spl->childNodes as $child) 
    {
        if (($child->nodeValue) !== '') 
        {
            echo \htmlspecialchars($child->nodeValue);

        }
    }
}
?>
```

**This Gives Output :**

```
ID1
2
Title 1
Oct 06, 2017

ID2
2
Title 2
Oct 05, 2017

ID3
2
Title 3
Oct 04, 2017
```

**Alternatively I tried :**

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//id') as $id) 
    {
        if (($id->nodeValue) !== '') {
         echo \htmlspecialchars($id->nodeValue);                
        }
    foreach ($xpath->query('//title') as $title) { 
        echo \htmlspecialchars($title->nodeValue); 
        }

    }
```

**But It gave Output as :**

```
ID1 Title 1 Title 2 Title 3
ID2 Title 1 Title 2 Title 3
ID3 Title 1 Title 2 Title 3
```

**I need Output as :**

```
ID1 Title 1
ID2 Title 2
ID3 Title 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change your foreach loop to

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//spl') as $spl) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate("string(descendant::id/text())", $spl);
    echo $xpath->evaluate("string(descendant::title/text())", $spl);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

This loops over all of the spl elements, then the inner XPath, fetches the id and title (descendant ensures it's only the items in the enclosing element).  Using `evaluate()` means that rather than fetching a node, in this case, the value returned is a string.  Also in `evaluate()` I'm using `$spl` as the start point for the query.

Comment: Thanks , for the simplest code ... some ppl make the code too complex..

Comment: I find it easier to write simple code :)  If it's solved your problem - can you mark it as answered - saves me trawling through questions later.